# Authetication failed

Tags: ubuntu-one, single-sign-on

After reinstalling Ubuntu One using the FAQs tutorial, when I try to log in, Ubuntu gives me the message: "**The authentication failed**".

I tried to recover the password (even knowing it), clicking on the button "**I've forgotten my password**", but when I entered my mail address, Ubuntu tells me "Sorry, we did not recognize the email address". I can sign in without problem using the browser.

I am using 12.04 32-bit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

See the following Ubuntu One FAQ: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-am-i-getting-an-the-authentication-failed-error-on-windows-225/